# Kivy Sprite Sheet

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

There is a way to crop sprites sheet in kivy?

For example, I have this sprite sheet:

[image: example image]

And i like to crop and create a list of separated sprites.

Like this:

```
spriteList = []

spriteW, spriteH = (32, 32)
imgW, imgH = (320, 320)

col = imgW // spriteW 
row = imgH // spriteH

for x in range(col):
    for y in range(row):
        cropped = cropImg(spriteW * x, spriteH * y) #THIS FUNC IS AN EXAMPLE
        spriteList.append(cropped)
```

Exists a way to do that in kivy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want to load the sprite sheet into a Texture (kivy.graphics.Texture), then in your loop create a series of TextureRegions using the texture coordinates of your sprites. You could then display these via a Rectangle graphics instruction.

You'll also want to set the texture interpolation of the Texture correctly, probably to 'nearest'.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, Kivy now comes with an Atlas system.

It is simply a json file, where the last name of the file has been changed to .atlas

The file contains the following structure:

```
{
    "<basename>-<index>.png": {
        "id1": [ <x>, <y>, <width>, <height> ],
        "id2": [ <x>, <y>, <width>, <height> ],
        # ...
    },
    # ...
}
```

Pretty simple as you can see, in this way you can chop up any image, and even multiple images to make one source for all your images and animations.

Obviously you can write a function that does this for you easy enough, but Kivy can also do the job itself through a console command:

```
python -m kivy.atlas <basename> <size> <list of images...>
```

Then to import the individual image-crops simply refer to them as source, but using an url like syntax:

```
Image(source='atlas://images/myatlas/id1')
```

So, in this example, images is the folder, myatlas the name of the atlas file (first name only), and the id the id you gave your particular image-crop.

Easy peasy stuff, read more about it here: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html